# AJAX reloads page after POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page containing a list of items. I want to be able to edit these items. To make this happen I have included an edit button to every item. When an edit button is clicked I use jquery / AJAX to to GET an edit form.

This works fine. However once the form (which has id="object-create") is filled in I once again want to use AJAX to POST the changes to my backend where I save them.

AJAX POST

```
$('#object-create').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var myform = document.getElementById('object-create');
    var fd = new FormData(myform );
    var post_url = $(this).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        data : fd,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data) {
            $('#result-container').html(data)
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("error")
        }
    });
});
```

However this does not work because the jquery event on my form never fires.

When I simply hard code the form into my page the event does fire and when I check it out in my browser's Inspector I see a little 'ev' symbol right next to

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="some_url/" method="post" id="object-create"> 'ev'
```

which is not there when I append this form via the AJAX GET request. I'm guessing I have to (re)bind the event to the inserted form, but I don't know how. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are adding a submit event to the form.

Instead, add a button to the form, (button of type button) **it helps stay consistent with what you are NOT trying to do**, add an event for the button and set button id to button1. Call your script from within this button. The form should no longer submit itself.

Here's an example I have you can learn a bit more in depth.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>ajax form submit</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- GOOGLE JQUERY JS v3.2.1  JS !-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <script>
        // Loads before document ready...
        $(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e) {

            ajaxPost();

            // Blur button1 for aesthetic reasons.
            $('#button1').blur();

        });


        $(document).ready(function() {

            console.log('1. Document is ready.');

            // Run the App.
            runApplication();

        });

        // We create a variable called runApplication and assign it a function runApplication()
        var runApplication = function runApplication() {

            console.log('1.0 runApplication() function called.');

            // ajax Post.
            ajaxPost();

        };

        /* Main AJAX function */
        function ajaxPost() {

            console.log('1.1 ajaxPost() function called.');

            //var data = $('#form1').serializeArray();
            console.log('2. Encode #form1 set of elements as a Serialized Array of objects (Names & Values)');

            // Serialized Array of objects from #form1.
            // Simulation purposes ONLY.
            var data = [{
                    "name": "client_id",
                    "value": "111"
                },
                {
                    "name": "project_id",
                    "value": "222"
                },
                {
                    "name": "user_id",
                    "value": "465605"
                }
            ];

            // data: Serialized Array of objects (Names & Values).
            console.log(data);

            console.log('3. Stringify this Serialized Array of objects (Names & Values)');

            // Stringify Serialized Array of objects.
            data = JSON.stringify(data);

            // data: Stringifyed Serialized Array of objects.
            console.log(data);

            console.log('3.1 data is now Valid JSON (RFC 4627).');
            console.log('3.2 data to be sent is of type: ' + typeof data);
            console.log('3.3 data is now ready for AJAX request.');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'php_pdo_mysql_insert.php', // url to post request to.
                method: 'POST', // method of request. POST & GET
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // contentType is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; charset=utf-8 for JSON
                dataType: 'text', // dataType is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text.
                data: data, // data to send. Use encodeURIComponent(data) whenever you want to send "problematic" characters in the URL such as &, % etc. The opposite is decodeURIComponent.
                timeout: 5000, // Longer than 5 seconds? HTTP SERVER or PHP Offline.***

                // AJAX beforeSend event...
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log('4. Ajax beforeSend* event fired.');
                },

                // AJAX success event...
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    console.log('4.1 Ajax success* event fired.');

                    console.log('4.2 data received is of type: ' + typeof data);

                    // If data return 1 = Successful Insert Query
                    if (data === 1) {
                        console.log('Status: MySQL Insert Successful.');
                    }

                    // If data return 2 = Database Connection refused
                    if (data === 2) {
                        console.log('Status: MySQL Connection Refused.');
                    }

                },

                // AJAX error event...
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // If http server and/or PHP is/are offline...
                    if (errorThrown === 'timeout') {
                        console.log('5. Ajax error* event fired.');
                        console.log('5.1 Ajax errorThrown* timeout* of 5 seconds reached.');
                        console.log('5.2 Status: NGINX or PHP offline?');
                    }

                }
                // AJAX done event...
            }).done(function() {

                console.log('4.3 Ajax done* event fired.'); // Fired ONLY on success event fire.

                // AJAX fail event...
            }).fail(function() {

                console.log('5.3 Ajax fail* event fired.'); // Fired ONLY on error event fire.

            });

        } // END ajaxPost()

        // Loads before document ready...
        $(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e) {

            // Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click.
            e.preventDefault();
            // Call ajaxPost() function..
            ajaxPost();
            // Blur button1 for aesthetic reasons.
            $('#button1').blur();

        });
    </script>


    <form id="form1">

        Client ID: <input type="text" name="client_id" value="111">
        <br> Project ID: <input type="text" name="project_id" value="222">
        <br> User ID: <input type="text" name="user_id" value="465605">
        <p>
            <button type="button" id="button1" ">button1</button>

</form>

Check Web Console <strong>Ctrl + Shift + K</strong>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But then I would still have to rebind an event to the button when I create the form.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood, your form is not present when the page initially loads and you are dynamically-creating a form after the page loads.

Change `$('#object-create').on('submit', function(event){` to `$(document).on('submit', '#object-create', function(event){`. For more information, read this section on [event propagation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation).

Side-remark: simplify your code by just doing

```
$(document).on('submit', '#object-create', function (event){
     event.preventDefault();

     // "this" is your form

     var fd = new FormData(this);
     var post_url = this.action;
     // etc
});
```